# Where to look for drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I want to know from where i can get all the drivers for Ubuntu 14.10 for my lenovo G580 laptop.
Is there any link for getting drivers for ubuntu ?

Comment: what isn't working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lenovo laptops are the best supported computers for most any flavor of linux, including Ubuntu.  As a result, you should not even need to seek drivers for them as such drivers tend to be automatically installed at installation time.  A couple of years ago I saw one Lenovo laptop which had failed to have its drivers properly installed because the internet wasn't connected during installation.  If your computer has a wired ethernet port, I recommend using that during installation.  If you don't wish to reinstall, you could open system settings and click on the "additional drivers" icon.

PS: Ubuntu is really the easiest operating system to install, the only caveat being that there are quite a few laptops which resist installation, most of them being made between 1998 and 2004.  The only way to tell is to boot such computers to the live cd/usb stick.  If it doesn't work with those, it probably won't work on the hard disk installation.

Here's another tip.  when in doubt, try disconnecting the internal hard drive and installing instead on a high performance external usb stick or hard drive as a "dry run test".  I am particularly fond of the Patriot Rage Pro XT sticks.  32g is overkill so these drives, for all their performance, don't actually cost that much. Best of all, after you have made your customized external stick, you can apply it to many valid purposes, not the least of which is introducing your friends computers to ubuntu by running their windows pcs to Ubuntu.  These sticks will also facilitate data recovery on your friends computer even when their windows is so corrupted that the machine wont boot.  You can save your friends hundreds of dollars by assisting them in data recovery, or of course you can probably persuade them to give you a few bucks for the service.  I suppose that may depend on how fond you are of them.  ;-)

Almost forgot, if you install CLAMtk VIRUS SCANNER on the stick you can help your friends to see how much malware and viruses their windows computers are suffering from.  Pay close attention as most of these are password stealers and scamware, so your friends will thank you when they see how much danger they are in.  My guess is they'd pay you to install Ubuntu for them.  It can be great fun. (or profitable) but at present I don't even charge for this simple service.